# Recieve data sent in request via AJAX in HTTP Response from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, xmlhttprequest

I am sending multiple AJAX requests by looping through a split string.  I need to associate the response with the request. I'm trying to receive the data provided in the AJAX request in the HTTP response.  I need this because I am making multiple requests and the responses are coming back asynchronously.  It appears the synchronous functionality of AJAX is deprecated.

My javascript:

```
var ingredientName = "";
var regExpNumber = /\d+/;
var inputRecipe = $('#addRecipe fieldset input#inputRecipeIngredients').val();

//split up the string into pieces for analysis and matching   
var recStringArray = inputRecipe.split(/[ ,]+/);
//need to do some kind of error checking in the future

//step through each piece of the string
for(var i=0; i < recStringArray.length; i++) { 
    //check each array item for numbers 
    var volumeCheck = (recStringArray[i].match(regExpNumber));

    //Check each array item that isn't a number to see if it is a unit of measure
    if (volumeCheck == undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/recipes/uomsearch/' + recStringArray[i],
            data: { 'key' : recStringArray[i]}
        }).done(function( response1, response2 ) {
            // Check for a successful (blank) response
            if (response1.length == 0) {
                console.log("didn't find UOM");
                ingredientName += response2;
                console.log(ingredientName);               
            }
            else {
                for(var y=0; y < response1.length; y++) {
                    var p = response1[y].root;
                    console.log(p);
                }   
            }
            });
    }//end of uom check for non-number array items
}
```

My recipes.js code running on the server:

```
router.post('/uomsearch/:key', function(req, res, res2) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('uomlist');
    var query = req.params.key

    res2 = query;
        console.log(res2);
    collection.find({'key': query},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "async:false" to the code causes the code to block and wait for the response before continuing.  This allowed me to capture the index of the array and store the data.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/recipes/uomsearch/' + recStringArray[i],
        data: { 'key' : recStringArray[i]},
        async: false
 })
```